# How to use GDI Libraries in C++

Tags: c++

I am a student of programming, and have programmed in many different languages.
However, I have used c++ only once and in a very non-professional way.
I have had no formal training in c++, and yes I am doing something about that, as it causes tons of confusion when things look very different from say Java, which I have had formal training in.

A lot of help I try to find recently has been so non-concrete I have gotten no where with almost all my questions, and here is a very specific one:

I wish to make a very simple game. I have never been shown concretely how to render graphics. I want to use the most basic library I can to render them, which from what I can tell (in Windows that is) is GDI. I found this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d420az6e(v=vs.110).aspx

When I try to #include or use the namespace the classes say they are a part of, errors pop up like crazy.

Why is that? How to I import these classes so I can use them?

Comment: That documentation is for the .Net version. Which is fine if you are coding in C# or C++/CLI, but no use at all if you are writing pure C++.

Comment: maybe all you need is a windows sdk?

Comment: @AlanStokes, fancy seeing you here :).

CAA14, you'll want the C++ api version of GDI called GDI+, which can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. That said, that's a pretty old API and I wouldn't want to use it or learn it for new development. For gate development you'll most likely want to look into Direct2D and similar APIs.

Comment: @TimoGeusch I understand that, and agree. Its just if I used DX or anything that isn't innately built into the OS, my end users will have to download something. Plus, I really want to learn the nitty gritty of stuff like this. I know, weird, most people say just use a game maker but I really, really want to know this stuff. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you have is for GDI+, not GDI. Despite almost identical names, they are not the same thing. GDI provides the most basic access to the display, via C calls only (no classes or any other OO stuff) and dates back to Windows 2.0.
GDI+ is more modern and has some improved capabilities, but it's still a bit outdated. As mentioned in the comments to your question, that link is for the .net API, if you're writing a native C++ application you won't be able to use it.

There is a native interface for GDI+, via COM. Take a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Ah, I see. So Windows supports GDI but in order to develop with it you must download the SDK or library for GDI+. In other words, end users wouldn't need to download anything to use an application that employs GDI+ or GDI, since Windows supports GDI and GDI+. But, I need the source code libraries so I need to download the SDK. Am I right on this?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can also use just GDI calls, but it's a lot more work and some "newer" features (like .jpg decoding) won't be available (I'm using quotes here because GDI is so old JPEG can be considered a novelty to it). But in either case you'll need the SDK header files and export libraries to link your program against GDI or GDI+ entry points. There are no "real" source (i.e. .c/.cpp) files involved, though.

Comment: For bare-bones GDI calls, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx and be prepared for the toil.

Comment: About the end user not needing to download anything, that's correct. All the needed DLLs are already part of the basic OS install (unless the OS of your user is really old, like pre-XP. I'm not sure when GDI+ was introduced, but  I know it was already available at least in XP.)